# How To Store/Retrive from S3 As JSON

Tags: java, json, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to upload and retrieve data from S3 via a lambda, however it currently returns data as a string. How do I return it as a JSON object.

For example this is the data I'm storing, through manual upload to S3:

> {
>   "data": [ 
>   {
>       "encryptedString": "D31BKNI8yVwknKXadWIP9LSL06Oss9Xhc5qyZSBHTBDj8TQihTHjoinKJEoKRT03Pt8U/b81ZLxuSOJxw3MU+ZX/CgSolBUPWeH/gD6zA/yKR+aQ0vb/t3g1SysTaOiKK2i5cGuqy3FLbgenn2U43sYKpb97B9h/WKCjGISBsMw="
>   } ] 
>   }

Lambda is triggered with this Java code:

```
public static void cryptoFromLambda(S3Event s3Event) {
    System.out.println("Called from Lambda. Records are:");
    s3Event.getRecords().forEach(e -> {
        try {
            String bucket = e.getS3().getBucket().getName();
            String key = e.getS3().getObject().getKey().replace('+', ' ');
            key = URLDecoder.decode(key, "UTF-8");

            AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client();
            String body = s3Client.getObjectAsString(bucket, key);
            System.out.println(body);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
    });
    System.out.println("end lambda");
}
```

Each line in CloudWatch is printed...

>  15:26:46 {
>
>  15:26:46 "data": [{
>
>  15:26:46 "encryptedString": "D31BKNI8yVwknKXadWIP9LSL06Oss9Xhc5qyZSBHTBDj8TQihTHjoinKJEoKRT03Pt8U/b81ZLxuSOJxw3MU+ZX/CgSolBUPWeH/gD6zA/yKR+aQ0vb/t3g1SysTaOiKK2i5cGuqy3FLbgenn2U43sYKpb97B9h/WKCjGISBsMw="
>
>  15:26:46 }]
>
>  15:26:46 }

... whereas I need each line as an element of JSON, of which I can then parse.

I think my issue is more in how I tell S3 that it should take what I input as JSON rather than just a text file, if it's possible to do that.

Comment: I don't understand.  `body` is a JSON string.  Yes, it happens to have newlines but it's still a JSON.  What are you trying to get to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer is to getObject and then get the content as a stream. One can then use Jackson's JsonParser to parse the stream

```
S3Object s3Object = s3Client.getObject(bucket, key);
S3ObjectInputStream s3Stream = s3Object.getObjectContent();

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = objectMapper.getFactory();
JsonParser jsonParser = jsonFactory.createParser(s3Stream);

JsonParser.nextToken()...etc
```